# Regex for escaping only a certain set of characters

Tags: c#, regex

I noticed that there is [a Regex.Escape method in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but that only escapes certain characters.

Is there a regex to escape any occurance of the characters `',",_,%,\` with `\',\",\_,\%,\\` respectively?

Comment: How about RegEx.Replace? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The reason those characters in particular are escaped, is because they also have meaning to the RegEx engine. Escaping other characters which don't have meaning is not very useful.

Comment: I am trying to escape those characters so that the string would be valid for another query. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm

Comment: aaaaah querying with built strings... the horror... the pain...

Comment: Building queries with custom strings is not advisable. Try to work with parameters instead and let the framework do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a C# regex to test out your approach, here is one that will work with `\$1` replacement string:

```
(?<!\\)(['"_%]|\\(?!['"_%\\]))
```

C# code:

```
var ptrn = new Regex(@"(?<!\\)(['""_%]|\\(?!['""_%\\]))"); 
var result = ptrn.Replace(@"',"",_,%,\, \"", \',\_,\%,\\,", @"\$1");
```

It will correctly escape your set of characters and won't touch already escaped ones:

```
\',\",\_,\%,\\, \", \',\_,\%,\\,
```

However, the regex approach might not be the one you should take (see comments to your question).